# How do I understand the compatibility of the tensorflow packages when i get below error?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Here is the ss of my cmd promt
[image: Error: Cannot register 2 metrics with the same name:]

The script is taken from github and the requirement of the problem is
Python 3.6.1

- Tensorflow 1.15
- tensorflow-probability=0.8.0
- Keras 2.25
- RDKit
- scikit-learn

But I have the latest versions:
Python 3.8.10

- Tensorflow 2.11
- tensorflow-probability=0.18
- Keras 2.11
- RDKit
- scikit-learn 1.9.3

I tried various versions of tensorflow (2.5, 2.6.1) but still it shows the same error.Can soemone tell me how to check compaatibility of packages with each other?

Comment: Add minimum code sample.

Comment: Please check if you have installed correct tensorflow and python version in your system as per this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#tested_build_configurations). Also make sure the tensorflow and keras version should be the same. TF 1.x is deprecated to use, so it's recommended to use TF 2.x. Please have a look at this [migration guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) to convert `TF 1.x` code into `TF 2.x`.